# wordpress "Colormag theme" error message in my brand new website

Tags: wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404

Hello I am new to wordpress.I created a wordpress account from hostinger and i tried a few themes initially and then finalised a theme called "Colormag theme".I went to preview.Now I am getting error message in my website-404.website picture is distorted.can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

I tried literally everything. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone here able to help me? Hostinger customer care guy asked me to come to this website